How do I modify just the header row of a csv file in python?
I am new to python but making decent progress.  I am getting data from AlphaVantatge to analyze various stock patterns.  The problem I am having is the header of the dataframe is not matching up with the data.  My data should be:
Date  Open  High  Low  Close  Volume
It ends up looking like this:
,1.,open,2.,high,3.,low,4.,close,5.,volume,
date,
IOW, the "date" column header is on the second line with the space for it blank on the top line (note the empty space before the first comma.)  Then it is grabbing numbers with the labels and throwing a comma between the number and label.  (ie:  1, open.......  vs Open)
I do not need the numbers as part of the labels.  I am wondering the best way to do this?  I have looked at various commands like strip() but am not sure which is best to use and exactly what syntax to use?  (Like I said, new to python.  I am getting the process needed but not always the syntax.)
Thanks in advance.
I have looked at various possibilities but everything I am searching seems to be about merging the entire column while I just need to merge the headers/names.

Your data query should be in the right format with your request and you shouldn't need to do anything. So, here is how to get the data (I chose stock prices from alphavantage):
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

time_series_data = data['Time Series (5min)']

df = pd.DataFrame(time_series_data).T  

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'index': 'timestamp', '1. open': 'Open', '2. high': 'High', '3. low': 'Low', '4. close': 'Close', '5. volume': 'Volume'}, inplace=True)

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

df.sort_values(by='timestamp', inplace=True)

print(df.head())

which should give you exactly what you expect:
            timestamp      Open      High       Low     Close Volume
99 2024-04-12 10:50:00  184.2000  184.2700  183.9200  184.0700  21733
98 2024-04-12 10:55:00  184.0600  184.2800  183.9870  183.9900  28103
97 2024-04-12 11:00:00  183.9700  184.4800  183.8600  184.4400  26258
96 2024-04-12 11:05:00  184.4300  184.6200  184.3700  184.4400  26268
95 2024-04-12 11:10:00  184.4200  184.6300  184.3700  184.5600  59181

